# Strange characters in HTTP GET response

Tags: android

I'm trying to figure out why special characters in a JSON feed (that looks completely fine when viewed in a browser) will break when used in my Android code. Characters with accent marks, ellipsis characters, curly quote characters and so on are replaced by other characters--perhaps translating it from UTF-8 down to ASCII? I'm not sure. I'm using a GET request to pull JSON data from a server, parsing it, storing it in a database, then using Html.fromHtml() and placing the contents in a TextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much experimentation, I narrowed down possibilities until I discovered the problem is with the Ignition HTTP libraries (https://github.com/kaeppler/ignition). Specifically, with ignitedHttpResponse.getResponseBodyAsString()

Although that's a handy shortcut, that one line results in the broken characters. Instead, I now use:

```
InputStream contentStream = ignitedHttpResponse.getResponseBody();
String content = Util.inputStreamToString(contentStream);


public static String inputStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

        // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        // Read response until the end
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line);
        }

        // Return full string
        return total.toString();
    }
```

Edit: Adding more detail

Here is a minimum test case to reproduce the issue.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

    activity = this;

    instance = this;

    String url = SaveConstants.URL;
    IgnitedHttpRequest request = new IgnitedHttp(activity).get(url);
    InputStream contentStream = null;
    try {
    IgnitedHttpResponse response = request.send();

    String badContent = response.getResponseBodyAsString();
    int start = badContent.indexOf("is Texas");
    Log.e(TAG, "bad content: " + badContent.substring(start, start + 10));
    contentStream = response.getResponseBody();
    String goodContent = Util.inputStreamToString(contentStream);
    start = goodContent.indexOf("is Texas");
    Log.e(TAG, "good content: " + goodContent.substring(start, start + 10));
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error", ioe);
    }
}
```

In the log:

> bad content: is Texasâ good content: is Texas’

*Update:* either I'm crazy, or the problem only occurs in the clients' production feed, not their development feed, although the contents look identical when viewed in a browser--showing "Texas’". So perhaps there's some wonky server configuration required to cause this issue... but still, the fix for this issue when it occurs is as I outlined. I do not recommend using response.getResponseBodyAsString();

Comment: ignition uses Apache's `EntityUtils` to generate that string. From the docs: "Read the contents of an entity and return it as a String. The content is converted using the character set from the entity (if any), failing that, "ISO-8859-1" is used." Check if your server responds with a wrong encoding.

Comment: If you still think it's wrong, please file a bug against Apache Commons HttpComponents.

Comment: I've used ignitionhttp a lot (and even droidfu). Sending html inside a json data structure is usually pretty well preserved and usable from the start (I dont have to compensate for any extra encoding).  Like  Matthias said, check the server encoding and maybe provide us with some examples to help you out better.  @Matthias , yer my hero bro. I hope whereever you are, you are doing well.

Comment: If you are storing values in a db,  please check there that data is preserved correctly there too.  (just a thought).